# Getting the full name for SimpleXMLElement with namespace

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When using SimpleXMLElement in PHP is there a way to get the namespace or the full name for an element that has a namespace?

For example, with the element

```
<namespace:name>...</namespace:name>
```

SimpleXMLElement::getName() only returns `name` and getNamespaces() returns an array of all the namespaces from the document. I would like to be able to get the specific namespace that the element uses, in this case `namespace`, or the full name, `namespace:name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this directly in SimpleXML right now. Luckily, however, you can "re-wrap" a `SimpleXMLElement` object as a `DOMNode` object using [`dom_import_simplexml`](https://www.php.net/dom_import_simplexml). This doesn't re-process the XML, it just puts a different PHP object around the same internal data structure.

You can then access the information you need from the properties of the `DOMNode` object:

```
$domNode = dom_import_simplexml($simpleXmlElement);
$nsPrefix = $domNode->prefix;
$nsUri = $domNode->namespaceURI;
```

Bear in mind that the *prefix* (`namespace:` in your example) is entirely local to the current XML document, and even the current *section* of the XML document, so should not be interpreted as having permanent meaning.

The "real" namespace of the element is the namespace URI, which is the permanent identifier the local prefix has been bound to. So if you want an unambiguous representation of the element, you might use the format `{http://example.com}SomeElement`, i.e. `'{' . $domNode->namespaceURI . '}' . $domNode->localName`

Answer (score 1):

> [SimpleXMLElement::]getNamespaces() returns an array of all the namespaces from the document

No, that is `SimpleXMLElement::getDocNamespaces()`.

`SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces()` returns the namespaces of the element.

The first key/value of the returned array is the namespace-prefix/namespace-uri of the element itself (if it has one which we assume in this case<sup>1</sup>), all following are additional ones, e.g. of element attributes.

Example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$sx = simplexml_load_string(<<<XML
<x xmlns:aed="http://aecommerce.org/schema" xmlns:edi='http://ecommerce.org/schema'>
  <!-- the 'price' element's namespace is http://ecommerce.org/schema -->
  <edi:price units='Euro' aed:more="test">
    32.18
  </edi:price>
</x>
XML, null, 0, 'http://ecommerce.org/schema');
// XML example from https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-using

var_dump($sx->price->getNamespaces());
```

```bash
/usr/bin/php8.1 -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=1 /home/hakre/sxml-namespace.php
array(2) {
  ["edi"]=>
  string(27) "http://ecommerce.org/schema"
  ["aed"]=>
  string(28) "http://aecommerce.org/schema"
}
```

If you leave out the attribute in the XML, the array entry is gone:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$sx = simplexml_load_string(<<<XML
<x xmlns:aed="http://aecommerce.org/schema" xmlns:edi='http://ecommerce.org/schema'>
  <!-- the 'price' element's namespace is http://ecommerce.org/schema -->
  <edi:price units='Euro'>
    32.18
  </edi:price>
</x>
XML, null, 0, 'http://ecommerce.org/schema');
// XML example from https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-using

var_dump($sx->price->getNamespaces());
var_dump($sx->price->getDocNamespaces());
```

```bash
/usr/bin/php8.1 -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=1 /home/hakre/sxml-namespace.php
array(1) {
  ["edi"]=>
  string(27) "http://ecommerce.org/schema"
}
array(2) {
  ["aed"]=>
  string(28) "http://aecommerce.org/schema"
  ["edi"]=>
  string(27) "http://ecommerce.org/schema"
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It would be otherwise in the *default namespace*.

Comment: There is one important caveat to this approach: it will not correctly report elements which are *not* in a namespace, because it does not create an entry unless there is a namespace URI to mention. See https://gitlab.com/imsop/simplexml_debug/-/issues/11

Comment: Sure, but when accessing the element we already know, see the fourth (and hidden fifth) parameter of `simplexml_load_string` in the examples.

Comment: That's just the equivalent of running `->children('http://ecommerce.org/schema')` immediately on the object. So yes, If you've just selected a namespace using that, or using `->children()`, you know that's the namespace you're looking at - but in that case you don't need a function to retrieve it anyway. If you're just looking at a single node out of context, you can't make any such assumption. https://3v4l.org/0GUlh

Comment: Unless you refer to self having a namespace-uri or not: https://3v4l.org/P2NXq

Comment: That feels a lot more convoluted (and probably slower) than using the DOM functions as in my answer. The reality is that it's one of many things that could easily be added to SimpleXML but isn't currently there; one day, I hope to add some of them.

Comment: @IMSoP: Sure, just because you asked for it ;) There is only one (very little) benefit: It works as well for elements that aren't yet added on which dom_import_... throws.